# Unable to convert value of type System.String to OData type [Edm.Guid Nullable=True]

Tags: c#, odata

My User class is like below when I try to update record using below query it gives me exception.

```
public class User
{
    public User();

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public Guid? LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public Guid? CityId { get; set; }
}
```

code

```
            Guid cityId = new Guid("4B1FCCA6-3E43-44BA-8516-BC693F02E9B5");

            await myClient.For<User>()
            .Filter(t => t.CityId == cityId)
            .Set(new { LanguageId = languageId  })
            .UpdateEntryAsync();
```

after executing above update statement i'm getting exception
`Unable to convert value of type System.String to OData type [Edm.Guid Nullable=True]`
`myClient` is `Simple Odata client`

Comment: what is `myClient`? what is `userData`? where do you get the error?

Comment: updated question with details

Comment: What is the type of the local variable `languageId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `LanguageId = languageId` is giving you this error because Guid type is different. One is .net inbuild and one I think you are getting from your service call. Also, I think  `languageId` here is string which is causing the problem

As defined here http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/

```
Edm.Guid : Represents a 16-byte (128-bit) unique identifier value.
```

Comment: thanks but what should be done in this case? how do I check ? both are `Guid` only thing is inside User class CityId is nullable ` public Guid? CityId { get; set; }`

Comment: on the second thought, LanguageId = languageId is the error line.. what is languageId here?